# Is it possible to use a menu navigation with HTML in PowerBI?

Tags: html, powerbi

Recently, I started using HTML for some visualizations within PowerBI. I would like to know if it's possible to use it for report page navigation, and if anyone has been successful, could you please show me an example?

That was the way I tried :

```
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Menu de Navegação</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Menu de Navegação</h1>
    <ul>
        <button onclick='window.location.href = 'https://app.powerbi.com/groups/########';'>Próxima Página</button>

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```